# What is the Delphi equivalent of C# generic list

Tags: delphi, com

How can we translate this c# line of code in Delphi. ?

```
List<InputMonitor> m_inputMonitors = new List<InputMonitor>();
```

Comment: Seems there is no any COM call in the line you provided. And i have no ideas what "InputMonitor" is and what "List" is in your app/lib. You should provide some details - what you are trying to do in Delphi.

Comment: "You think"? You mean you don't know what is it? You are trying to translate some code from C* to Delphi, but you don't know what this code is actually doing? Anyway, if you have TInputMonitor class doing "something", then David already provided translation you asked for.

Comment: I answered the question you asked. Please don't edit to ask an entirely different question. If you want to ask a new question, make a new question. But, if that question is just, "please translate my code", it's not a real question.

Comment: @David Ok, I've something to start with, and if we have many question about the same source (not asking to translate the whole) do you know a better place or a better way to use stckoverflow ?

Comment: You could post the code and ask somebody to explain what it does. Don't ask for translation. Just ask for a high level overview of what it does. Make sure you set it in good context. Question might be, I'd like to do X, I found this C++ code to do it, but I don't understand. Please can someone give a high level overview of what the code does and how it manages to do X. However, even that might attract flak. You'd need to show that you'd tried hard to understand. Perhaps explain what you understood already, and what you did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not C++. It's probably C# or Java. Let's assume it is C#. The code simply instantiates a new instance of a specialized containter class. The equivalent class in Delphi is `TList<TInputMonitor>`.

The translation is:

```
uses
  Generics.Collections;
....
var
  InputMonitors: TList<TInputMonitor>;
....
InputMonitors := TList<TInputMonitor>.Create;
....
```

Comment: Tlist is a generic array, but to pass it to something non-delphi you would need the address of element 0 of the array. But iirc that is private.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort The translation is accurate no? You cannot pass a .net generic to a COM method either.

Comment: We see TStringList often, is it better to use TList or TStringList ?

Comment: Impossible to say. Depends on the application.

Comment: @AlainV: Google for "1": 17.610M hits.   Now Google for "2":16.980M hits. --> Is it better to use "1" or "2"? :)

Comment: @Wouter, definitely 1 :-)

Comment: @Tlama: Yeah, Google confirms it. Ok, make that "1" beer for TLama please!  :-)

Comment: DavidHeffernan: afaik you can get the address of the element array in C++ container types, not so sure about tlist. But I didn't check.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Merry Christmas. In C++, the equiv class is std::vector and operator[] returns a reference. But the code in the Q is C# which does not have references in quite that way.

Comment: Merry Christmas. Apparently I need to calm down with the wine :_0